# Subtract a specific value based on the value of 2 other columns in R

Tags: r

I have data frame (GDPPerCap) with columns for Year, Country.Code and GDPperCapita. For example:

```
Year     Country.Code     GDPperCapita
1960     AUS              15,000
1960     USA              20,000
1960     ARG              8,000
.
.
.
2018     USA              60,000
```

I want to setup a new column for a specific country (for example, USA) such that the value is equal to the GDPPerCapita variable for that row, minus the GDPperCapita for the USA in 2018. (Eventually I want to set up a loop so that it creates a similar column for each different country code.

I have tried using mutate:

```
GDPPerCap <- GDPPerCap %>%
```

`mutate(USA_Difference = GDPperCapita - GDPperCapita[Country.Code == "USA", Year == "2018"])`

I want it to achieve:

```
Year     Country.Code     GDPperCapita   USA_Difference
1960     AUS              15,000         -45,000
1960     USA              20,000         -40,000
1960     ARG              8,000          -52,000
.
.
.
2018     USA              60,000          0
```

Apologies, this is my first post and haven't quite nailed it. But hopefully you get my point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the GDP per capita for USA in 2018 by doing

```
USA2018 <- GDPPerCap %>% filter(Country.Code=="USA",Year == 2018) %>% pull(GDPperCapita)

# Note: if Year is in character format you might have to do Year == "2018" instead
```

Then the code you provided should work

```
GDPPerCap <- GDPPerCap %>% 
                       mutate(USA_Difference = GDPperCapita - USA2018)
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up changing this a little to extract the 2018 value for all countries. This way I can create a loop to make a variable for all countries. but thanks for the idea. The concept worked well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use vectors and assign to the table directly

```
GDPPerCap$USA_Difference <- as.numeric(paste(GDPPerCap$GDPperCapita))-as.numeric(paste(GDPPerCap[GDPPerCap$Year=="2018" & GDPPerCap$Country.Code =="USA",3]))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am getting NAs introduced by coercion. Can you explain why I would have the year equal to "4", and what the 3 at the end does?

Comment: Sorry. Year should be equal to "2018". I edited the answer.

Comment: 3 means that the third column in the data frame which is the "GDPPerCapita" column. I'm basically calling the values in the third column.

Comment: It will take the value in the third column which satisfies the conditions. In this case the country code and year should be equal to "USA" and "2018" respectively.